# How to get particular fields from document and sub-document in single document in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : 5000758100,
    "lines" : {
        "objId" : 5000758106
    }
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 5000758100,
    "lines" : {
        "objId" : 5000758107
    }
}
```

Above is sample document.
Need to fetch all the distinct objID values along with common _id in document.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "ids":{
                $push:"$_id"
            },
            "objIDs":{
                $addToSet:"$lines.objId"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "distinct":{
                $setUnion:["$ids","$objIDs"]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Data set:**

```
{ "_id" : 5000758100, "lines" : { "objId" : 5000758106 } }
{ "_id" : 5000758101, "lines" : { "objId" : 5000758107 } }
```

**Output:**

```
{ "distinct" : [ 5000758100, 5000758101, 5000758106, 5000758107 ] }
```